# OpenCV Eye Tracking looses out for some frames

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, eye-detection

I am pasting code below to track both eyes and overlay an image when both eyes are tracked.
I am using haar xml files to track both eyes of faces and overlaying an image over it.
My problem is I get result like this.

**Img 1**

[image]

**Img 2**

[image]

**Img 3**

[image]

**Img 4**

[image]

**Img 5**

[image]

**Img 6**

[image]

**Img 7**

[image]

**Img 8**

[image]

**Img 9**

[image]

**Img 10**

[image]

I am posting my code below

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame );
String face_cascade_name = "/root/opencv/newtutorial/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String eyes_cascade_name = "/root/opencv/newtutorial/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
RNG rng(12345);
IplImage *disp,*neg_img,*cpy_img,*imga;
IplImage *pic;
IplImage  *image_n = 0;
int make=0;
CvMat* warp_matrix = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
namespace {
    void makevdo(){
        bool flag = false;
        fstream fin;
        char filename_new[200],filename_new_after[200];
        int n=0;
        Mat frame;
        double frameRate = 25.0;
        CvVideoWriter *vdowriter = cvCreateVideoWriter( "/root/opencv/newtutorial/test_converted_next.mov", CV_FOURCC('j','p','e','g'), frameRate, Size(640,480) );
        VideoWriter(outputFile,CV_FOURCC('j','p','e','g'),frameRate,Size(640,480));
        while(flag==false){
            sprintf(filename_new,"/root/opencv/newtutorial/mydirnext/filename%.3d.jpg",n);
            sprintf(filename_new_after,"/root/opencv/newtutorial/framesaftertrack/filename%.3d.jpg",n);
            fin.open(filename_new,ios::in);
            if( fin.is_open() )
            {
                frame = imread(filename_new);
                pic = cvLoadImage("/root/opencv/newtutorial/pic.png");
                image_n = cvLoadImage(filename_new,1);
                disp = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(image_n), 8, 3 );
                cpy_img = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(image_n), 8, 3 );
                neg_img = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(image_n), 8, 3 );
                std::vector<Rect> faces;
                Mat frame_gray;
                cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
                equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );
                face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
                CvPoint2D32f q[4];
                q[0].x= (float) pic->width * 0;
                q[0].y= (float) pic->height * 0;
                q[1].x= (float) pic->width;
                q[1].y= (float) pic->height * 0;
                q[2].x= (float) pic->width;
                q[2].y= (float) pic->height;
                q[3].x= (float) pic->width * 0;
                q[3].y= (float) pic->height;
                for( int i = 0; i < (int)faces.size(); i++ )
                {
                    faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 2, 8, 0 );
                    Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
                    std::vector<Rect> eyes;
                    eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
                    if((int)eyes.size()==2 && (((eyes[0].x + eyes[0].width*0.5 ) < eyes[1].x) || ((eyes[1].x + eyes[1].width*0.5 ) < eyes[0].x))){
                        CvPoint2D32f p[4];
                        IplImage* blank  = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(pic), 8, 3);
                        cvZero(blank);
                        cvNot(blank,blank);
                        if(eyes[0].x<eyes[1].x){
                            Point center0( faces[i].x + eyes[0].x + eyes[0].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[0].y + eyes[0].height*0.5 ); 
                            float radius0 =  (eyes[0].width + eyes[0].height)*0.25 ;
                            Point center1( faces[i].x + eyes[1].x + eyes[1].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[1].y + eyes[1].height*0.5 ); 
                            float radius1 =  (eyes[1].width + eyes[1].height)*0.25 ;
                            p[2].x= (float) center0.x - radius0;
                            p[2].y= (float) center0.y + radius0;
                            p[1].x= (float) center0.x - radius0;
                            p[1].y= (float) center0.y - radius0;
                            p[3].x= (float) center1.x + radius1;
                            p[3].y= (float) center1.y + radius1;
                            p[0].x= (float) center1.x + radius1;
                            p[0].y= (float) center1.y - radius1;
                        }
                        else{
                            Point center0( faces[i].x + eyes[1].x + eyes[1].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[1].y + eyes[1].height*0.5 ); 
                            float radius0 =  (eyes[1].width + eyes[1].height)*0.25 ;
                            Point center1( faces[i].x + eyes[0].x + eyes[0].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[0].y + eyes[0].height*0.5 ); 
                            float radius1 =  (eyes[0].width + eyes[0].height)*0.25 ;
                            p[2].x= (float) center0.x - radius0;
                            p[2].y= (float) center0.y + radius0;
                            p[1].x= (float) center0.x - radius0;
                            p[1].y= (float) center0.y - radius0;
                            p[3].x= (float) center1.x + radius1;
                            p[3].y= (float) center1.y + radius1;
                            p[0].x= (float) center1.x + radius1;
                            p[0].y= (float) center1.y - radius1;
                        }

                        cvGetPerspectiveTransform(q,p,warp_matrix);
                        cvZero(neg_img);
                        cvZero(cpy_img);
                        cvWarpPerspective( pic, neg_img, warp_matrix);
                        cvWarpPerspective( blank, cpy_img, warp_matrix);
                        cvNot(cpy_img,cpy_img);
                        cvAnd(cpy_img,image_n,cpy_img);
                        cvOr(cpy_img,neg_img,image_n);
                    }
                }
                cvSaveImage(filename_new_after,image_n);
                cvWriteFrame(vdowriter,image_n);
                cout<<"Read file filename"<< n <<endl;
            }
            else{
                flag=true;
            }
            fin.close();
            n++;
        }
        cvReleaseVideoWriter(&vdowriter);
        cvReleaseImage(&pic);
        cvReleaseImage(&imga);
        cvReleaseImage(&disp);
        cvReleaseImage(&neg_img);
        cvReleaseImage(&cpy_img);
        cvReleaseImage(&image_n);
    }

    int process(VideoCapture& capture) {
        char strFrame[]="/root/opencv/newtutorial/mydirnext";
        if(mkdir(strFrame,0777)==-1)
        {
            cout<<"Error Trying to delete"<<endl;
            if(system("rm -r /root/opencv/newtutorial/mydirnext")){
                cout << "Directory successfully deleted"<<endl;
            }
            if(mkdir(strFrame,0777)==-1){
                cout << "Error Again creating directory" << endl;
            }
        }
        int n = 0;
        char filename[200];
        string window_name = "video | q or esc to quit";
        cout << "press space to save a picture. q or esc to quit" << endl;
        namedWindow(window_name, CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);
        Mat frame;
        for (;;) {
            capture >> frame;
            if (frame.empty())
                continue;
            imshow(window_name, frame);
            sprintf(filename,"/root/opencv/newtutorial/mydirnext/filename%.3d.jpg",n++);
            imwrite(filename,frame);
            char key = (char)waitKey(5);
            switch (key) {
            case 27:
                if(make==0){
                    make=1;
                    makevdo();
                }
            return 0;
            default:
            break;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
int main(int ac, char** av) {
    if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
    if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
    if (ac != 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    std::string arg = av[1];
    VideoCapture capture(arg);
    if (!capture.isOpened())
        capture.open(atoi(arg.c_str()));
    if (!capture.isOpened()) {
        cerr << "Failed to open a video device or video file!\n" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return process(capture);
}
```

Sorry for posting so many Images SO, but No other way to explain my problem.

Comment: This code is a mess. Help yourself and simplify it as much as you can, and please remove the dead code.

Comment: I am new onto this...If you will help me pointing some of my code it will be really helpful...

Comment: Dead code = code that makes absolutely no difference in the logic of your program, like the variable `make` for instance. You also have commented out code, so there's no point to keep it around and you should erased it. These are all tips to make your code clear. I would also review code indentation. By making your code clearer, you have more chance of people getting interested in it.

Comment: Done as you said bro....Please help me out...Will be really thankful...

Comment: Take your hat off?  It might confuse the face detection...

Comment: Hat is not a big deal...It affects the result but code is not 100 % consistent with or without cap....

Comment: can you provide your configuration xml files?

Comment: haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml  http://www.esnips.com/doc/ada6353d-8240-49b6-8310-97b00dc83d3b/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses  haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml  http://code.google.com/p/warai/downloads/detail?name=haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by extracting everything to methods/functions that you can be given a sensible name. We don't want to see methods longer than 10 lines. The images are not helpful at all. Remove the overlay and show what the algorithm claims to recognize, when it does so.

After you've done that, feed it sequences of the same images. First the ones where it recognizes, then those where it doesn't. That way you can get a better guess where the problem is. But first clean up the messy code.

Comment: thats not the answer.
i need help seriously.
help with some code or least reference